# Redirecting from a Document link to new sharepoint site Page

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, redirect

The scenario is as such:-

There exists a word document in a document library. We know that we can directly access this document with a specific URL.

Now I want this to happen :-

Whenever someone goes to this document link URL, he/she should get redirected to new SharePoint site page rather than the document itself.

I have read about one way that is '`Symmetrical Rewrite URL`', but does we have any other way to do this?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Are you need to redirect to SharePoint site page that will show the clickable document or only redirect to site page ?

Comment: Simply redirect to a SharePoint site page from an exact document link URL, for example :- https://consto.sharepoint.com/Edgeconsto/_layouts/15/WopiFrame.aspx?sourcedoc={12260714-2BEC-4570-97F8-8D673527D503}&file=systematicRewrite.docx&action=default    to   https://consto.sharepoint.com/Edgeconsto/home.aspx

Answer (score 1):

I have a workaround to your request via Jquery by

- Checking if the current URL have a specific value based on your URL I put ('&file=') as a value that repeated to all URL when I open documents.
- Redirect to your URL.

So.

- Open the Document library page > Edit it.
- Add content editor or script editor web part and make sure you have a reference to Jquery. (`/Style%20Library/js/jquery.min.js`)
- Paste the following code.

> ```
> <script type="text/javascript">
> $(document).ready(function () {
>     if(window.location.href.indexOf("&file=") > -1) {
>       window.location.href = "http://consto.sharepoint.com/Edgeconsto/home.aspx";
>     }
> });
> </script>
> ```

Comment: I am also here if you need more clarification

Comment: M.Qassas thank you for replying but i do not get you here, content editor web part will be added to to document library , but i am talking about a word document(opened) in sharepoint online. I need to redirect that link to a new sharepoint site page.

Comment: M.Qassas sir i mean to ask how do i add a web part to a document? I know how to add a web part to a document library but how to add a web part to a documnt directly?

Comment: you are right let me check if there is method to check the url before navigation

Comment: Okay! I am here waiting till that.

Comment: Put above script in master page

Comment: and for direct hitting of url you can use browser add-on since you cannot access server